# I expected my alignment of the table to be automatically placed. But it didnt

Tags: html, sql, format

I am trying to create an HTML table that will send out a table to me.
However, I am not very familiar with the formatting and it has caused me to have some alignment problem.
Can anyone help me on how I can make the structure works?

This is my output at the moment
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuDXs.png)

I do not know how to align it.

Thanks!

I expected my alignment of the table to be automatically placed. But it didnt

Code:

```
SET @tableHTML =  
    N'<H1>Anaplan Summary Report </H1>' +  
    N'<table border="1">' +  
    N'<tr>' +
    N'<th width="20%">Date</th>' +  
    N'<th width="20%""><font color="black">Interface Name</font></th>' +
    N'<th width="20%"><font color="black">Successful</font></th>' +  
    N'<th width="20%"><font color="red">No of Failed Process</font></th>' +  
    N'<th width="20%"><font color="red">Process not triggered</font></th>' + 
    N'</tr>' +  
    'Anaplan'+'  '+CAST  ((SELECT   CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 101)  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE )
    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  )
                +'  '+ CAST( @total_record_count AS varchar)+ '  '+ 
    CAST(@total_pass_count AS varchar)+
    N'</table>'
```

Comment: Paste your HTML into https://htmltidy.net and click View --> Blocks.  Or pipe it through `/usr/bin/tidy -iq`

Answer (score 0):

Chua Ricky, Could you post the HTML Table code you are using?

I have some similar code that I am using with Bootstrap 5 that might help you. It's using a PHP backend and PDO to return entries from a Contact table in a MySQL database. The `include_once` points to the .php file containing the PDO connection to the database information. I keep my includes outside of my webroot directory.

```
<?php
include_once('../../includes/PDO-Connect.php');

echo('<div class="offset-md-1 col-md-10"><table class="table caption-top table-bordered border-primary">
<caption class="h4 text-center">Contact Us Submissions</caption>
<colgroup>
  <col class="text-center sqltbl1">
  <col class="text-center sqltbl1">
  <col class="text-center">
  <col class="text-center sqltbl2">
  <col class="text-center">
</colgroup>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
</tr>');
 $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Contact");
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo("<tr><td>".$row['FName']."</td><td>".$row['LName']."</td><td>".$row['eMail']."</td><td>".$row['Phone']."</td><td>".$row['Comment']."</td></tr>");   
 }
 ?>
</table></div>

</body>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.sqltbl1 {
  min-width: 80px;
}

.sqltbl2 {
  min-width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, i have edited my post and shared my code

Comment: After reviewing your photo of output and code, it looks like there is a missing <tr><td> tags in your output with closing </td> and </tr> tags for each data and row. In my code, you can see each returned row from SQL creates a new <tr> and each column in the table is output with it's own <td> and closing</td> tags, with a closing </tr> tag.  See the Echo statement in the PDO block.